# Existence of a point satisfying a given condition

Tags: complex-numbers, continuity

> Let $\mathbf{T}=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$ and $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{C}$ be continuous with $f(0)=0, f(1)=2$. Show that $\exists n\in [0,1]$ such that $f(n)$ is in $\mathbf{T}$.

I approached geometrically. Obviously $\mathbf{T}$ is the set of the points which are lying on the perimeter of unit circle in complex plain, centering at origin. Now the function $f$ starts at origin having value **zero**, is continuous, and at $z=1$, $f(z)=2$. Of course there is no way that a continuous curve moves from $z=0$ to $z=2$ without intercepting the unit circle. So we can always find at least one $n\in [0,1]$ such that $f(n)\in \mathbf{T}$.

Is this logic sufficient? Even if it is, I wonder whether I can prove it analytically without using the geometric concept. I believe that Intermediate Value Theorem will not be much helpful as we cannot compare two complex number to find which one is larger. So how  to proceed?

Comment: Is $\;C=\Bbb C=\,$ the complex numbers?

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes it denotes the set of complex numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the function $g:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $g(x)=|f(x)|$. The modulus function is continuous, so $g$ being it's composition with the continuous function $f$, is also continuous. As $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=2$, by intermediate value property $\exists~c\in(0,1)$ such that $g(c)=1$, or equivalently $|f(c)|=1$, hence $f(c)$ lies in $T$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. $F(x):=|f(x)|$ is a continuous function (why?) from $[0,1]$ to $[0,+\infty)$, such that $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=2$. Note that $f(x)\in \mathbf{T}$ if and only if $F(x)=1$. Then use the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) for the real function $F$.